# Angular 2 http.get is not sending the token in the header

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-http

I have a post method which is working and fetching my token from the server

```
authenticate() {
  let url = this.server + 'authenticate';
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  let body = JSON.stringify({
    'password': 'admin',
    'rememberMe': true,
    'username': 'admin'
  });
  return this._http.post(url, body, options)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe(result => this.token = result.id_token);
}
```

where `this.server` is a string having the url of the server. and `this._http` is just an instance of the angular Http

```
private _http: Http;
constructor(http: Http) {
  this._http = http;
}
```

and `this.token` is just an empty string `private token: string;`

Now all this is working just fine and I am getting the right token from the server. **My problem is** that when I try to use this token in a get method it doesn't work and I get a 401 (unauthorized) error.

My ***buggy*** get method is:

```
getData(src) {
  let url = this.server + src;
  let headers = new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token});
  return this._http.get(url, headers)
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .subscribe(res => console.log('res'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that I should have added `{}` around the headers when I sent them. the get should be `this._http.get(url, { headers })`

Answer (score 1):

Http.get takes a url string and an optional RequestOptionsArgs as parameters. Wrapping the header in a RequestOptions object should do the trick.

```
getData(src) {
  let url = this.server + src;
  let headers = new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token});
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  return this._http.get(url, options)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe(res => console.log('res'));
}
```

Comment: I actually had it like that and there is no difference what so ever

Comment: add a return in the .map() call  

`.map((res:Response => return res.json())`

Comment: Thank you for you, but that wasn't the problem. I wrote the answer if you want it

Comment: Using the {} might work, but the correct way is to use a RequestOptions object. I have updated my answer to reflect this.